# jQuery Popup flickers on fast mouse transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, hover

Popup works smoothly in slow mouse enter and leave transitions. But on fast transitions, sometimes flickers and at other times, stops appearing altogether on hover over the div element.

Code in jQuery:

```
var flag = 1;

jQuery('#hover').mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery('#popup').show();
});

jQuery('#popup').mouseenter(function(){
    flag = 0;
    jQuery('#popup').show();
});

jQuery('#popup').mouseleave(function(){
    flag = 1;
    jQuery('#popup').hide();
});

jQuery('#hover').mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { if (flag == 1) jQuery('#popup').hide();}, 400);
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/et65am4c/

How to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not really a Javascript problem. It's executing the commands you're telling it to execute. It might be better to just animate in the div so that it feels smooth.

The easiest way to do that would be with jQuery animate.

```
var flag = 1;
jQuery('#hover').mouseenter(function(){
    jQuery('#popup').stop().show('fast');
});

jQuery('#popup').mouseenter(function(){
    flag = 0;
    jQuery('#popup').stop().show('fast');
});

jQuery('#popup').mouseleave(function(){
    flag = 1;
    jQuery('#popup').stop().hide('fast');
});

jQuery('#hover').mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function() { if (flag == 1) jQuery('#popup').stop().hide('fast');}, 400);
});
```

A better way to do it though, would be with CSS transitions using the `opacity` property.